# Need help for running msi to exe file - java in wine

Tags: wine, java

A Linux newbie here. Transfered couple of days ago. I didn't make that smooth and flowingly suggestion and I move to Linux very impusively. After my 4th restart of Windows in 45 minutes I just purged my ssd and installed Ubuntu. I will learn it on the go, but I need to continue doing my regular job in the meantime, so I need help with running exe file.

So, I read about wine and Windows apps and I'm trying to run it, but here's the thing. Its msi installer which contain an exe file of the app, but this app is working in Java Environment. Pretty nice, huh?

So I managed to install it with wine, but I can't run the exe file. I tried the different topics which I found but nothing seems to work and I really need to get my things done with my job. Is anyone knowing how should I do this ? Already tried to install JRE in wine's hidden folders, but still not starting. Terminal gives me this error:

> ahbh@ubuntu-desktop:~$ wine SpankOddsLauncher
> 0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
> 0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
> 0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
> 0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
> Application could not be started, or no application associated with
> the specified file. ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install JRE for Windows under wine? I mean did you run something like `wine jre-[version]-windows-x64.exe` and was it successful? Try to use the full filename (absolute path or just cd into the dir with .exe and run `wine ./SpankOddsLauncher.exe`)

Comment: Yes I think I've managed to install java for Windows. What I did was :

``> cd /home/`whoami`/.wine/drive_c/users/`whoami`/
> mkdir -p appdata/LocalLow/Sun

I've installed java after that - manually. Went to ``wine explorer.exe`` and installed both of the istallers. Then I tried to start the exe file.

And it didn't show any error through the installation. So I assume it has been installed sucessfully. But when I try to start the exe file after installation - nothing happens.

Comment: I get :

``ahbh@ubuntu-desktop:~/wine/spank/drive_c/Program Files/SpankOdds$ wine /home/ahbh/wine/spank/drive_c/Program Files/SpankOdds/SpankOddsLauncher.exe
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0074:err:vulkan:wine_vk_init Failed to load libvulkan.so.1.
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
wine: failed to open "/home/ahbh/wine/spank/drive_c/Program": c0000135``

Comment: This is because you must mask the space char with a backslash or just quote the path:
`wine '/home/ahbh/wine/spank/drive_c/Program Files/SpankOdds/SpankOddsLauncher.exe'`

Comment: Tried to quote the path also. I get an error : "An error occured while starting the application. Bad EXE format for %1."